# Declare a flat, blacklist array and ignore blacklisted values in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I queried a table into an array but I would like to exclude certain values from one of the columns as to spits out each row.  For example.

```
foreach($results as $row)
{
         if($row['sku'] != "sku-1"){
             echo $row['sku']." ";
         }
}
```

So lets say the table has 4 rows with a value of sku-1, sku-2, sku-3 and sku-4.  The above Foreach code would echo out "sku-2 sku-3 sku-4".  Is there a way I can make an array of what values I would want to exclude?  Like I'd have an array called $skuarray = "sku-2, sku-4" and instead of

```
if($row['sku'] != "sku-2" || $row['sku'] != "sku-4"){
```

have that $skuarray in there where it'll echo "sku-1, sku-3"?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

I could somehow exclude it when I query it.  I'm querying it from table SKUTABLE and the column is SKU.  The problem is I need to exclude unique values from column SKU so I thought if there was an easy way to just throw in all the ones I want to exclude into an array that'd be great.

Comment: Can yoy exclude unwanted values ​​directly in the query?

Comment: Maybe [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `in_array`:

```
$skuarray = array("sku-2", "sku-4");

foreach($results as $row)
{
         if(!in_array($row['sku'], $skuarray)){
             echo $row['sku']." ";
         }
}
```

Comment: I guess I can change my ["Maybe"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489632/php-for-each-result-excluding-values-from-array#comment39783882_25489632) to "Use" lol

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `array_diff(array1, array2, [...arrayN])` function, which takes at least two arrays, and returns an array of only those values of array1 which are not in any of the subsequent arrays. Example:

```
$input = array(0=>'sku-1',1=>'sku-2',2=>'sku-3',3=>'sku-4');
$exclude = array('sku-1','sku-3','sku-4');
$result = array_diff($input, $exclude);
print_r($result);
```

Will print

```
array(1=>'sku-2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) in combination with [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array).

```
$filtered_results = array_filter($results, function ($row) {
    return in_array($row["sku"], $skuarray) === false;
});
```